# Finding root through bisection method

Tags: excel, vba

I was practicing Excel vba and tried to find root through Bisection method. I created userform where:

textbox1 - takes equation formula
textbox2 - lower point
textbox3 - higher point
textbox4 - accuracy

and optionButton to choose which method use to find root.

I guess the algorithm implemented is correct but results are not true. I guess there are some issues with working on textbox values

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

last = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EQ").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EQ").Cells(last + 1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EQ").Cells(last + 1, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EQ").Cells(last + 1, 3).Value = TextBox3.Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EQ").Cells(last + 1, 4).Value = TextBox4.Value

If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EQ").Cells(last + 1, 5).Value = "Bisection"


Dim xp As Double
Dim xk As Double
xp = (CDbl(TextBox2.Value))
xk = (CDbl(TextBox3.Value))

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EQ").Cells(last + 1, 6).Value = CSng(xm(xp, xk))

End If

(...)

Function xm(xp As Double, xk As Double) As Double

Dim eq as String
Dim fxp As Variant
Dim fxk As Variant
Dim fxm As Variant

xp = (CDbl(TextBox2.Value))
xk = (CDbl(TextBox3.Value))
eq = TextBox1.Text

fxp = (CDbl(Evaluate(Replace(eq, "x", xp))))
fxk = (CDbl(Evaluate(Replace(eq, "x", xk))))
fxm = (CDbl(Evaluate(Replace(eq, "x", xm))))


    Do
        xm = (xp + xk) / 2

        If fxp * fxm < 0 Then
            xk = xm
        Else
            xp = xm
        End If
    Loop Until Abs(xp - xk) < TextBox4.Value

End Function
```

Comment: What is `eq`? Please give a [mcve]. From a coding point of view, it would make sense to have the bisection function be a stand-alone function which doesn't depend on external text boxes and global variables. Pass it what it needs to do its job. That way, the code can be used in other places where you need a root-finder. The code that calls this function can be the code which interacts with input/output.

Comment: Note that `fxm = (CDbl(Evaluate(Replace(eq, "x", xm))))` is *before* `xm` is given a non-zero value. Furthermore, you are not updating the `f` values in the loop itself.

Comment: But when i try to move fxm after giving to xm non-zero value i get "Runtime error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `fxm = (CDbl(Evaluate(Replace(eq, "x", xm))))` is before xm is given a non-zero value. Furthermore, you are not updating the `f` values in the loop itself.

Here is an approach (which uses much of your code):

```
Function bisect(f As String, x As String, xp As Double, xk As Double, eps As Double) As Double
    Dim xm As Double
    Dim fxp As Double, fxk As Double, fxm As Double

    Do
        xm = (xp + xk) / 2
        fxp = (CDbl(Evaluate(Replace(f, x, xp))))
        fxk = (CDbl(Evaluate(Replace(f, x, xk))))
        fxm = (CDbl(Evaluate(Replace(f, x, xm))))

        If fxp * fxm < 0 Then
            xk = xm
        Else
            xp = xm
        End If
    Loop Until Abs(xp - xk) < eps
    bisect = xm
End Function
```

For example, `bisect("1-x-x^3","x",0,1,.0001)` evaluates to `0.68231201171875`

The motivation for making the independent variable a parameter of the function is that e.g. if you want to use a function which uses `exp()` you will be forced to do do something like use `t` for the independent variable.

You would use it something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim eq As String
    Dim xp As Double, xk As Double, eps As Double, root As Double

    eq = TextBox1.Value
    xp = CDbl(TextBox2.Value)
    xk = CDbl(TextBox3.Value)
    eps = CDbl(TextBox4.Value)

    root = bisect(eq, "x", xp, xk, eps)
    MsgBox root
End Sub
```

The code itself is not very robust. It simply assumes that `fxp` and `fxk` are of opposite signs. If this assumption is false, the results are garbage, so some input validation (which raises an error if needed) might be appropriate.

Comment: As I understand, I need to pass variables from commandButton_click to function. Why to pass x? Intention was to only swap x from equation.

Comment: I explained the point of `x`. There is no way that `"exp(x)"` would work with a simple `replace` approach. The event handler for the click event can handle the function invocation.

Comment: Could give me some hints how to write CommandButton_click? I have difficulties with declaring esp and perhaps with passing variables to function.  Esp I treated like xp before, I mean i declared  'Dim esp As Double = (CDbl(TextBox4.value))'  but got error of type mismatch

Comment: @HannibalLecteur See the edit. I don't think that you can combine `Dim` and assignment to a textbox value like that.

Comment: Thank You very much for your help. But I have one more question. This solution works only when there is no fractions. Im not sure if its beacause I convert to double result of evaluation or something with commas and dot. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @HannibalLecteur If you want to enter things such as `1/2` in the text boxes, a simple workaround would be to replace `Cdbl` by `Application.Evaluate` in the code for the click event.

Comment: I guess I didn't express myself too clearly. What i wanted to say is that if any variable gets floating point value, the result of function is equal to eg 2029. I tried with replacing dots to commas in declarations but it didn't helped

Comment: @HannibalLecteur What is a specific example of inputs which don't work as you expect?

Comment: for instance, `if f = x - 2, xp = 0.5, xk = 4, eps = 0.001` the value of fxp is 2015

Comment: @HannibalLecteur I can't reproduce that behavior. When I evaluate `?bisect("x-2","x",0.5,4,0.001)` in the immediate window I get `1.9996337890625 ` Furthermore, if I put `Debug.Print fxp` in the code for `bisect()` (just after the assignment to it) it doesn't print any values that are anywhere near 2015.

Comment: I see that `?Application.Evaluate("0,5")` leads to `Error 2015`. VBA knows nothing about regional settings. What you could do is use `Replace()` to swap out commas for decimal points: `Application.Evaluate(Replace("0,5",",","."))` evaluates to `0.5.`, so in the userform something like `Application.Evaluate(Replace(TextBox2.Value,",","."))` should work.